# How to extend ImageCases?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision

I was very excited to see `ImageCases` being documented in version 12. But I immediately desired a mechanism for adding more entities to `ImageCases`, especially given that we can create our own custom entities now.

Assuming you have many images containing a new object class and you want to detect them and their `ImageBoundingBoxes`, is there any undocumented method or 3rd party service to achieve this?

I’m thinking that there might be a way to combine `Classify` with the new Image Pyramid functionality and/or `ImageCases`’s internal feature network and do some transfer learning.

Comment: The model of ImageCases is NetModel["Wolfram ImageCases Net V1"] which maybe based on YOLO V2. I hope we can simply replace the model by InceptionV1 in Mathematica 12.0.1 or 12.3...? And hope Wolfram describes more about how to train their models.